# How to script /etc/issue?

Tags: terminal, arch-linux, login, prompt, tty

I would like to pipe my tty number through figlet (ASCII generator) for the `/etc/issue` (message shown before login). Obviously this means I can't just update it from `/etc/rc.local`.

On my system (Arch), `agetty` is responsible for parsing the file.

Comment: It seems you're going to need to hack your own agetty replacement or at least write a wrapper :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this, but one solution would be to run your figlet command and redirect the output into /etc/issue.tty{1-11}, effectively hard-coding the figlet output for each tty.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the linuxlogo package.  Check it out like this:

```sh
$ apt-cache search linuxlogo
linuxlogo - Color ANSI System Logo

$ sudo apt-get install linuxlogo
...

$ linuxlogo -L list
```

Comment: The OP is looking for an Arch solution, not a Debian/Ubuntu one...

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/linux_logo/ is the Arch native package.